# Windows batch file count and display each loop

Tags: batch-file, command, cmd

I am putting a batch together to run a propitiatory audio converter.  The batch works, you put it into a folder and dump each file you need to convert into the same folder, it loops through each one and outputs the converted file into a folder names converted.  When you run it, it sits there until completed.  What I am trying to do is at the beginning of each loop say something like "converting file 1" "converting file 2" and so on so the user can see some progress.  I just have no clue how to add that in.  Here is what I have so far.

```
@echo off
color Fc
echo Remember to put this program and the audio files to convert into the same folder!!!!!
pause
if not exist converted MD converted
for /r . %%f in (*.wav) do "C:\Program Files\Verint\Playback\CommandLineConvertor.exe" "%CD%\%%~nxf" "%CD%\converted\%%~nxf"
echo All files have been converted
pause
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your `DO` to multiple lines, and echo in the loop, like this:

```
for /r . %%f in (*.wav) do (
    ECHO Converting %%f . . .
    "C:\Program Files\Verint\Playback\CommandLineConvertor.exe" "%CD%\%%~nxf" "%CD%\converted\%%~nxf"
)
echo All files have been converted
```

Alternately, if you want to show the whole path, just echo the first parameter you used, like this:

```
for /r . %%f in (*.wav) do (
    ECHO Converting "%CD%\%%~nxf" . . .
    "C:\Program Files\Verint\Playback\CommandLineConvertor.exe" "%CD%\%%~nxf" "%CD%\converted\%%~nxf"
)
echo All files have been converted
```

**EDIT:**

It would help if I read your requirement fully.  You can increment a number like this:

Add `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` after `@ECHO OFF` to enable delayed expansion of variables.  Then, before the loop, initialize your variable:

```
SET /a x=0
```

Then in your loop, increment the variable and ECHO it, giving you this:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
color Fc
echo Remember to put this program and the audio files to convert into the same folder!!!!!
pause
if not exist converted MD converted
SET /a x=0
for /r . %%f in (*.wav) do (
    SET /a x=x+1
    ECHO Converting file !x! . . .
    "C:\Program Files\Verint\Playback\CommandLineConvertor.exe" "%CD%\%%~nxf" "%CD%\converted\%%~nxf"
)
echo All files have been converted
pause
end
```

Comment: This will work perfectly if i cant figure out counting, only down side is this audio files have pretty long names, so if I can keep the output a little cleaner that would be great, but great idea I didnt even think about just displaying the file name.

Comment: +1. @brock029, as an additional feature, it's easy to include the total number of files in the message like, 'Converting file 1 of 25 . . .', useful if it runs with lots of files. To implement this run a copy of the `for` loop once first without the audio processing command, or `echo`. Keep the `set` but change the var to `filecount` (don't forget to `SET /a filecount=0` before the loop). Then in the main loop `ECHO Converting file !x! of !filecount! . . .`. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for...now next weird problem.  It outputs double the amount of files being converted.  For example with 2 audio files it says converting file 1 - converting file 4...any ideas?

So like this:
Converting file 1...
Converting file 2...
Converting file 3...
Converting file 4...
All files have been converted

Comment: @brock029, Are the output files .wav and in the same dir? Is it possible you're picking them up? Add code to print the file name out so you can see what's going on.

Comment: @jimhark also great!  A co-worker of mine suggested i add that on.  and to your second post you dump the files into the folder with the batch in it.  for the decoder you run CommandLineConverter.exe "input file" "output file".  Ill remove echo off and see what i get.  But yes the output are also .wav just different encoding but the script is creating a sub-dir called converted and dumping them in there, could the for loop be searching the sub-dir too?

Comment: No the new files should not be picked up if they are in a separate dir.

Comment: @jimhark I just double checked and it is running correctly just for each file it runs twice and outputs only 1 file in the converted folder.

Comment: Also added on your suggestion and followed the way you added it on to the answer and i get.  

Converting file 1 of 2 ... Converting file 2 of 2 . . . converting file 3 of 2 . . . Converting file 4 of 2 . . .  Its really weird.

Comment: Got it fixed, this time had it output to a folder on the desktop and it is getting the numbers correctly.

Comment: Sorry about that, got sidetracked, but glad it got worked out!

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables no problem and thanks to you and jimhark for helping me get this worked out!

Comment: To show the complete path, you can also use `"%%~ff"` instead of `"%CD%\%%~nxf"`. (`%%f` may not be a good choice as a loop variable name in this particular case, by the way. You could at least call it `%%F`, as `%%~fF` might be slightly less confusing to read. I would just use a letter that isn't used as a modifier, though.)